# Mezclando datos de 2 arreglos de datos

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

//necesito unir estos dos arreglos

```
array = [
  { name: 'usuario', email: 'usuario@gmail.com' },
  { name: 'usuario1', email: 'usuario1@gmail.com' }
]
```

```
arra1 = [
  { email: 'usuario@gmail.com', asistencia: true },
  { email: 'usuario1@gmail.com', asistencia: false }
]
```

// que devuelva esto con un return

```
arrayAsisten =[
    { name: 'usuario', email: 'usuario@gmail.com', attendance: true },
    { name: 'usuario1', email: 'usuario1@gmail.com', attendance: false }
]
```

//necesito mezclar o unir los arreglos sin duplicar los datos en un funcion con dos parametros pero aun no encuentro como.

Comment: Qué has intentado? el tercer arreglo tiene nombres de propiedades de diferentes, y los "names" no hacen sentido con los primeros 2 arreglos, quizá te equivocaste

Comment: e intentado con un for y aplicar intruduciendo dato por dato pero no lo regresa bn

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes leer [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < usuario.length; i++) {
 if (usuario[i].email == asistencia[i].email ) {
    usuario[i].name = asistencia[i].name
 }

Comment: El [repro] debe ir en la pregunta misma, no como comentario, ya que es información esencial de la pregunta. Como verás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios.

Comment: okey ya lo agrego

Answer (score 1):

Podría ayudar tener un identificador único para cada usuario, así puedes filtrarlo por medio de este más fácilmente.

Solo mapeas tu arreglo principal, luego lo filtras para encontrar las coincidencias y ya luego solo muestras tu array extendido como (...array)

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'usuario',
    email: 'usuario@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'usuario1',
    email: 'usuario1@gmail.com'
  }
]

const arra1 = [{
    id: 1,
    email: 'usuario@gmail.com',
    asistencia: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: 'usuario1@gmail.com',
    asistencia: false
  }
]

const joinArray = array.map(item => {
  const daily = arra1.find(element => item.id === element.id);
  return daily ? { ...item,
    ...daily
  } : { ...item
  }
});

console.log(joinArray)
```

Comment: si te das de cuenta no son datos iguales lo que tienen en comun es el email y necesito que solo regrese un arreglo con los dos datos con su nombre email y asistencia

Answer (score 1):

// este seria la respuestas muchas gracias igualmente se puede aplicar con un for
// usamos el metodo map para busca el item de email en ambos arreglos ya que son los unicos similares en ambos usando una funcion flecha retornando le dato de date dando asi una igualdad de los elementos donde de igual manera esta siendo gradados en allDate luego siendo retornada espero me puedan entender.

```
 function mergeData(users, attendances) {
 let allDate = users.map(item => {
   const date = attendances.find(element => item.email === element.email);
   return date ? {
     ...item,
     ...date
   } : {
     ...item
   }
 });
 return allDate
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: okey, intentare explicarlo